# connect 2 router remotely on differnet isps and locals

Tags: networking, router, internet, remote, isp

In my scenario (as shown in the picture), a router is located in a country or city that passes through the ISP filter to access a specific domain, and therefore it has limited access to the internet.

But the second router is in another place, such as another city or country, which has unlimited unfiltered access to the internet. Is it possible to connect the first router from the internet to the second modem and from the second router as an intermediary to access a specific domain?

I mean, use router 2 as proxy-like server for router 1.

[image]

Comment: In your image router 1 and router 2 are "directly" connected to the same ISP (ISP 1). Is that actually the case? I think you mean to connect router 1 to the second router via this route: `router 1 <-> ISP1 <-> Internet <-> ISP2 <-> router 2`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to set up a VPN-Server on the second router or on a machine connected to the second router. This is assuming:

- The second router has a public IP address (meaning it is not behind a carrier-grade NAT)
- ISP 1 lets you access router 2 over the internet (and doesn't block the traffic going to or coming from router 2).

There are loads of options for VPN servers, either already integrated with your router (or with an alternative firmware) or you can run a VPN server on a machine connected to the router e.g. [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/)

Another possible solution would be to use a remote desktop connection (Teamviewer, Anydesk, VNC, etc.), that works without a public IP as long as you create an account. Or a remote login (via RDP, VNC, SSH, etc., which will require a public IP).

Please note that for a more specific answer, more specific information is needed about the routers, your ISPs, and the firewall restrictions used by ISP 1.

Comment: no.there is no option to create RDP connection,only access to routers setting menu are available. so there is no way to setup vpn on pc clients that are connected to routers.but routers have virtual server, NAT , ip routing options capability.does it help?

Comment: @marya9011 no, it doesn't, you have to be more specific and say what exactly is available (and what isn't and why). Also please explain the use case, do you want to access a website or do s.th. else? Please add the information to your question, not just into the comment. Please try to put more effort into your writing, you are hard to understand.